# Loading Images with Picasso into RecyclerView from External Drive - Android App

Tags: java, android, picasso, android-recyclerview

I recently had an issue where I couldn't work out how to add any photos I take with my app into the phone's gallery.

I have now achieved this.  My issue though, is when I am retrieving the photos I take onto the app from a Firebase database.

I have the following code using picasso to get my photos (this is from an Adapter class):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
    holder.textViewName.setText(uploadCurrent.getName());
    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.imageView);
}
```

If I take photos with the stock camera on the phone and upload these to Firebase via the app, when I come to retrieve them and show on my phone, they are fine.  However, if I take a picture with the app I created, it uploads to the Firebase database okay but won't retrieve the picture.  There is the placeholder for it with the image title but no actual image.  I'm wondering whether it's something to do with the orientation but I'm not sure.

Has anyone got any suggestions?  All welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please give us the urls of the images in both cases?

Comment: It is the same in both cases "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/frapp-58a8a.appspot.com/o/uploads%2F1519220455552.jpg?alt=media&token=c976c923-4793-4e16-8016-c524e900d150"

Comment: Any ideas?  I still haven't been able to come up with a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

On further research, I decided to give Glide a try instead of Picasso and it worked.

So, instead of the above, replace 'Picasso' with 'Glide' and '.fit()' with '.fitCenter()'.

Also, add the following to the gradle (using the latest versions):

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

and change this line:

```
Picasso.with(this).load(mImageUri).into(mImageView);
```

to this:

```
Glide.with(this).load(mImageUri).dontAnimate().into(mImageView);
```

I hope that helps someone else in the future.